# Cannot determine if a feature branch is merged with integration branch if we do a squash commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Using the Github UI, if I merge a feature branch into the integration branch and choose "Squash and Merge", the tip of the feature branch is no longer incorporated into the integration branch.

If we didn't do a "Squash and Merge", then the tip of the feature branch *would* be in the integration branch.

So my question is - is there a reliable way to determine if a particular feature branch has been completely merged into the integration branch, if it was done with squashed commit?

One thing around this, potentially we could run this before merging the feature branch with the integration branch:

```
git reset --soft "remotes/origin/dev"
git commit -am "soft-reset-commit"
```

then with the Github UI, we would never do any squashing. But the problem with the above is that in order to push it to the remote, I have do:

```
git push -f
```

because I squashed the local, so the local feature branch does not have all the commits that the tracking remote has.

As long as people think that `git reset --soft` is safe and that my work won't get lost it might be a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I solved this at the moment is to checkout a new branch, squash that, and then push it to the remote. After merging the squashed branch into the remote integration branch, I can delete the squashed branch locally (because `git branch --merged <integration>` shows the squashed branch) and then delete the original branch too:

run this: `$ git fetch && git branch --merged <integration>` and we get:

```
feature/xyz@squashed
```

then I can go and delete

```
feature/xyz
```

as long as feature/xyz has no new commits since it was branched into the @squashed branch.